# access my own image files or load them in phoneoxpth from S3 to sage maker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm fairly new to working with AWS, and I want to use SageMaker to train a certain image data set using fast.ai. But I have no clue how to link all the image data from S3 to SageMaker.

I tried almost everything I could think of, used s3fs and I can read the images separately and the list of the images, but how do I feed that info to my databunch or learning algorithm?

My code:

```py
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

role = get_execution_role()
bucket='sagemaker-sst-images'
data_key = 'SST_Data/sst-images'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
```

This code, I think, gives a URL to the data. 
But what comes next? Either get it into a path, or load the data properly?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have boto3 imported, you can use that to [start a training job](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_training_job) in Sagemaker. It can read your training data straight from S3 to train your model on.

If you are using a custom model, this would require having your inference code in EMR

The way you could do it is like this (I use some of the vars you put in your question):

```
# Get a sagemaker client object for S3
sagemaker_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

# Create an input channel definition (for the training job call)
input_data = {
   'ChannelName': 'train',
   'DataSource': {
       'S3DataSource': {
          'S3DataType': 'S3Prefix',
          'S3Uri': data_location
        }
    },
   'ContentType': 'application/png' # This will depend on the type of your images
}

# Start the training job on Sagemaker 
sagemaker_client.create_training_job(
    TrainingJobName="My training Job",
    HyperParameters={ # These will be any hyperparameters you need },
    AlgorithmSpecification={
       'TrainingImage': # The ECR url to your algorithm goes here,
       'TrainingInputMode': 'File'
    },
    RoleArn=role,
    InputDataConfig=input_data,
    OutputDataConfig={'S3OutputPath': # Your S3 output path goes here for your trained model artifacts},
    ResourceConfig={
        'InstanceType': # whichever type/size of instance you want here
        'InstanceCount': # however many instances you want to train with,
        'VolumeSizeInGB': # however much storage space you need for your training data on the instance
    }
)
```

Here is some information regarding the instances sizes and prices:
https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/instance-types/
https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/

for `ContentType` in the input config, here is a resource for more info on the MIME type you need: https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/

After the training completes, you can use the model artifacts it creates to make a SageMaker model, and use it to perform inference.